# $yu_x +4u_y = 0$, where the characteristics are parabolas: $y^2 - 8x =$ const.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Are there any special tips and tricks how to choose the right initial condition for PDE?

I was given the equation $yu_x +4u_y = 0$, where the characteristics are parabolas:  $y^2 - 8x =$ const.

Comment: It's quite unclear what you want to accomplish. What do you mean by choosing the right initial condition?

Comment: It is true that $y^2-8x$=constant are characteristic equations of the PDE $yu_x+4u_y=0$. But your question "how to choose the right initial condition for PDE?" is ambiguous or/and out of context. Of course a condition can be specified in the wording of the problem. But one doesn't chose it. If no condition is specified they are infinity many solutions. What do you mean exactly ?

Comment: I'm sorry, the task si unclear in general. Only thing I want is to choose a suitable condition and determine the particular solution. I don't want the exact solution, but some tips/instructions how to find/choose the right one that fits. 
For example I was given the eq. $4yu_x-xu_y = 0$ with init. cond $u(x,0)$ = sin x, which doesn't work. Now the task is reversd, that I have the eq. and I have to find init. cond that suits.
I chose f.e. $u(x,0)$ = cos x, which f.e. how can I tell thath fits? You can tell, that I'm new in this area. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$yu_x+4u_y=0$$
The method of characteristics leads to the general solution :
$$u(x,y)=F(y^2-8x)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function since no condition is specified. Thus they are infinity many solutions.

EXAMPLES OF CONDITIONS :

1. Case with the condition $u(x,0)=\sin(x)$

$u(x,0)=F(0-8x)=\sin(x)$

Let $X=-8x\quad\implies\quad x=-\frac18 X \quad\implies\quad\sin(-\frac18 X)=F(X)$.

The function $F$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where $X=y^2-8x$. The solution satisfising both the PDE and the specified condition is :
$$u(x,y)=\sin(-\frac18(y^2-8x))$$

2. Case with the condition $u(x,0)=\cos(x)$

$u(x,0)=F(0-8x)=\cos(x)$

Let $X=-8x\quad\implies\quad x=-\frac18 X \quad\implies\quad\cos(-\frac18 X)=F(X)$.

The function $F$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where $X=y^2-8x$. The solution satisfising both the PDE and the specified condition is :
$$u(x,y)=\cos(-\frac18(y^2-8x))$$

3. Other conditions :

On the same way a solution satisfising both the PDE and another condition can generally be found. You can specify the condition whatever you want. Your question  "Now the task is reversd, that I have the eq. and I have to find init. cond that suits." is incomprehensible.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't mention it.  Finding the general solution of a PDE is not so simple in the majority of cases. One have to know well the method of characteristics and this is far to be sufficient in many cases.